# How would a cursed mask work?

Tags: magic, parasites

I want to write a novel in which the main antagonist has a cursed mask that determines his "mischievous" attitude. Why would a symbiotic mask attach itself on this guy and make him bad (except from feeding)? The mask will make the guy a dictator that will fight for his country dominance over the others. What the mask will get from this, **I am asking for a need of a symbiote that has to be satisfied in order for it to want bloodshed.** I don`t care if the mask is conscious of it`s actions or not. I don`t want revenge to be the sole purpose of the mask.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87569/discussion-on-question-by-edward-constantin-how-would-a-cursed-mask-work).

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely up to you. Magic, curses and other supernatural terminology are a generally-accepted handwave, allowing the worldbuilder the freedom to provide as much or as little explanation as desired. And as a bonus, anything that has internal consistency and doesn't violate basic human anatomy is acceptable. But if you're looking for suggestions, how about these:

**No explanation.** The mask is simply cursed and the wearer is irresistably controlled.

**Telepathic power.** The mask has its own consciousness and possess the capability to telepathically control the wearer's mind.

**Parasitic tendencies.** The mask physically binds itself to the wearer and sends mind-controlling chemicals through the pores of his/her skin or the ear canals.

**Spiritual collaboration.** The mask appeals to local malevolent spirits to gang up on the wearer and overwhelm his/her soul to gain control over the body.

**Telekinetic power.** The mask bypasses the wearer's mind and directly controls his/her muscles telekinetically. *(Stop hitting yourself, stop hitting yourself!)*

Comment: The parasite leaving inside the mask is a very nice idea, can you tell me where I find some more examples and inspiration for it? The fact that the action in the book will take place in the distant future, after the apocalypse ended and the world rebuilded to the Medieval Era could also let me use some bio engineering for the creation of the mask

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to let the mask have a ghost/soul/spirit. The ghost/soul/spirit is evil and possesses (maybe just subconsciously changing the antagonist to evil) the person wearing the mask. The good guy finds out and bans/purifys/befriends the ghost/spirit/soul and uses the powers then against the antagonist. As a power the wearer of the mask could have:

- Poltergeist ablities: affecting matter without touching them or
- Spiritual attacks on the mind of the opponent
- Summoning of skeletons, letting the ghost/spirit/oul control them
- Entering a spiritual plane, what lets the wearer go trough walls and lets him fly

many more :)